# WCF - per call object caching

Tags: c#, wcf

I have re-worded my question.

From the server side code of my WCF services, I would like to cache a few variables. These variables need to be used through out the livecycle of one service call. I don't want them in every method signature call that may be used in the services logic.

If it was a web applicaiton I would use session management, but this is on the server code side. How do I 'cache' these values, per service call, and then dispose of them on service completion?

Solution:

The point of this was to track which service call had a error in a bug tracking tool. So in the end I did something like the following:

```
  public class MyService: IMyService
    {
         public String ServiceLogic(string var1, string var2, string id)
         {
             try{
                    DoingStuff.DoMoreStuff();
             }
             catch(exception ex)
             {
                 var trapper = MyCustomErrorTrap(var1,var2);
                 throw new faultexpection<MyCustomErrorTrap>(trapper);
             }
         }

}



Public static class DoingStuff
{
     public static void DoMoreStuff()
     {
         try{
             if(blah.toString())
             ........
         }
         catch(exception ex)
         {
            throw;
          }
     } 
}
```

Allowing the main calling method to trap all exceptions, I can then use the two variables that I need at the top level.

Comment: I'm reading two different questions here: 1) You want to log a caller id on error and 2) you have a set of values in addition to caller id you want access to from anywhere in the service's call stack. Am I right?

Comment: I am sorry I don't get the question, could you please expand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make sense to me.

> through out the livecycle of one service call

A "service call" - or a service operation - is just an invocation of a method within a service. You obviously need to pass the values in when the operation is called (or retrieve them from somewhere), so you'll already have them.

```
public class MyService : IMyContract
{
    public void DoSomething(string p1, int p2)
    {
        DoThing(p1);
        DoAnotherThing(p2);
    }
}
```

So why do the parameters need to be cached? Just use them within the context as required.

If you mean *cached per session*, that makes more sense. The solution is relatively simple:

```
// decorate your class like this
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class MyService : IMyContract
{
    // these fields will persist until the session is closed
    private string _p1;
    private int _p2;

    public void DoSomething(string p1, int p2)
    {
        _p1 = p1;
        _p2 = p2;         
    }

    // check that the _p1 and _p2 values are initialised before use
    public void AnotherServiceOperation()
    {
        DoThing(_p1);
        DoAnotherThing(_p2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the lines DoThing(_P1);  almost like a global variable. (Hate globals though). This gave me an idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* go to a Session-based model, but I imagine that's too heavy for what you want to do.

I also imagine that you currently pass the id with each call to your WCF service(s).

That said, you could create a specific exception type which would take two parameters in the constructor.  The first is the id of the caller (which you would expose as a property) and the second is the exception which will be passed to the [base constructor of the `Exception` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/804f22sf.aspx) and exposed through the [`InnerException` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx).